# SimpleLucene cannot implement interface member

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I'm trying to follow [these instructions](http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/SimpleLucene-e28093-Lucenenet-made-easy.aspx).
I should also mention that I am using the [NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/SimpleLucene) as opposed to the [CodePlex](http://simplelucene.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) source.

I'm presented with these 2 errors:

> Error 1
>   'LuceneTest.Models.ProductIndexDefinition' does not implement interface member 'SimpleLucene.IIndexDefinition.GetIndex(LuceneTest.Models.Product)'. 'LuceneTest.Models.ProductIndexDefinition.GetIndex(LuceneTest.Models.Product)' cannot implement 'SimpleLucene.IIndexDefinition.GetIndex(LuceneTest.Models.Product)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Lucene.Net.Index.Term'.
>
> Error 2
>   'LuceneTest.Models.ProductIndexDefinition' does not implement interface member 'SimpleLucene.IIndexDefinition.Convert(LuceneTest.Models.Product)'. 'LuceneTest.Models.ProductIndexDefinition.Convert(LuceneTest.Models.Product)' cannot implement 'SimpleLucene.IIndexDefinition.Convert(LuceneTest.Models.Product)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Lucene.Net.Documents.Document'.

From this code:

```
using System.Web;
using SimpleLucene;
using Lucene.Net.Documents;
using Lucene.Net.Index;

namespace LuceneTest.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductIndexDefinition : IIndexDefinition<Product>
    {
        public Document Convert(Product p)
        {
            var document = new Document();
            document.Add(new Field("id", p.Id.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new Field("name", p.Name, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            return document;
        }

        public Term GetIndex(Product p)
        {
            return new Term("id", p.Id.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

When I look at IIndexDefinition in object explorer it looks like this:

```
public interface IIndexDefinition<T>
    where T : class
{
    Lucene.Net.Documents.Document Convert(T entity);
    Lucene.Net.Index.Term GetIndex(T entity);
}
```

I don't understand what's going on. I mean the error are saying that the class is not implementing the interfaces because the return types do not match but I'm just not seeing where or how I can fix it.

Comment: Same problem occured in my super simple 4.0 console project.
Two dependency exists in framework. I think someway the document and term conflicted for different versions. But could not not solve still.
'Lucene (≥ 2.9.2.2)'.
'Lucene.net (≥ 2.9.4.1)'.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is Nuget package is not a valid package. Download the latest source of simplelucene. You can see tests working with 2.9.4.2. Replace your 2.9.4.1 lucene.net with this dll.

Comment: Is the project not supported anymore or why have they not corrected this issue? Do you know?